# C# wpf textbox while

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, while-loop

I am making a WPF program to determine how many hours it takes to make a certain amount of bread.

I need the user to enter

- The amount of bread they want made
- The capacity they can create bread per hour

and It should give the results with how many hours the bread has been baking and the capacity that was baked at for that hour so for 130 pieces of bread at capacity 50 the result would be

```
1-50
2-50
3-50
```

I believe the issue is in my while loop but am not exactly sure what the problem is.
Currently I am not getting the desired output, although the program will compile.

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int Bread = 0;
    int Capacity = 0;
    int Time = 0;
    int InitialTime = 0;
    Bread = int.Parse(txtBread.Text);
    Time = int.Parse(txtTime.Text);
    InitialTime = int.Parse(txtInitialTime.Text);
    Capacity = int.Parse(txtCapacity.Text);

    while (Bread > 0)
    {
        if (Bread > Capacity)
        {
            Bread -= Capacity;
            txtResult.Text = txtResult.Text + "\n" + (Bread - Capacity).ToString();
            InitialTime += Time;
            txtResult.Text = txtResult.Text + "\n" + (Bread - Capacity ).ToString(); 
        }

        else
        {
            Bread -= Capacity;
            txtResult.Text += Bread.ToString(); 
            InitialTime += Time;
        }
}
```

Thank you everyone :)

Comment: binding is your friend

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's unclear what you're asking here. Check out [How to Ask](stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: thanks nate, but could you tell me ,what is unclear here, because english is not my native language, maybe ia have a mistake in vocabulary

Comment: also look under these numbers 11-50 // 12-50 // 13-50. there you have the explanation

Comment: Grant Winney the program is not runnig :(, just stucking of freezing

Comment: @progrkito The issue Nate is getting at is your question and the problem with you're having isn't made clear in your question body. Your question should include information (code, errors, etc.) showing the issue, your attempts to fix said issue (research, similar questions, resources) and the desired result (what you intend the program to do that it's not currently doing). Check the form on [How to Ask a Good Question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I know you have already asked this, and I tried to help you but your question is so hard to understand I apparently didn't.

So the while loop looks good how I made it except the results don't make sense because I don't know what you want.

I'm going to try and translate your problem to something I understand, you show us what the results should look like, but not what they are. It looks like you want the amount of hours the bread has been being made, and the capacity for that hour

```
string printString = "";
int totalTime = 0;
int timeInterval = 1;
while (Bread > 0)
{
    if (Bread > Capacity)
    {
        Bread -= Capacity;
        totalTime += timeInterval;
        printString += string.Format("{0} - {1}\n", totalTime, Capacity);
    }

    else
    {
        Bread -= Capacity;
        totalTime += timeInterval;
        printString += string.Format("{0} - {1}", totalTime, Capacity);
        txtResult.text = printString;
    }
}
```

This will run the While loop when Bread is greater than 0, it will enter the if statement if there is still more bread than the amount of bread you can make
and every time through the loop it will take capacity off the bread and add an hour to the time.

On the last run through bread will be less than capacity and it will run through the else statement, then it will put the printString in the result textbox  it will make bread less than 0 and will end the loop.

If this isn't somehow what you want then you need to be much much clearer on what you need help with.

I would also like to note in the code block above I only wrote variables I am using that you didn't already declare so don't take out all of your other variables if they are still being used in the code.

I made a full program to look at if you are still having trouble

CLASS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication7
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int bread = Convert.ToInt32(txtBread.Text);
        int capacity = Convert.ToInt32(txtCapacity.Text);
        string printString = "";
        int totalTime = 0;
        int timeInterval = 1;
        while (bread > 0)
        {
            if (bread > capacity)
            {
                bread -= capacity;
                totalTime += timeInterval;
                printString += string.Format("{0} - {1}\n", totalTime, capacity);
            }

            else
            {
                bread -= capacity;
                totalTime += timeInterval;
                printString += string.Format("{0} - {1}", totalTime, capacity);
                txtResult.Text = printString;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="69,42,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="txtBread" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="69,70,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="txtCapacity" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="255" Margin="221,42,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="txtResult" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="177"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,98,0,0"     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: thanks Scriven,its true that i asked this before, but I didn't get any answer, sot i posted again, I understand that the question isn't very clear, but i am new in programing field, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Did this help you, or is there something you still don't understand?

Comment: Also i have one question why in my code after some correcting code, now after i click button, the result is just zero

Comment: will you edit your question with the full .xaml.cs code

Comment: Never mind, I made the program anyway, you can look at my code if your having trouble